# Athena performance on too many S3 files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-athena, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I am planning to store data into S3 on top of which SQL queries would later be executed. The S3 file would basically contain json records. I would be getting these records through DynamoDB streams triggering AWS Lambda execution so its difficult to handle duplication at that layer as AWS Lambda guarantees `atleast once delivery`.
To avoid handling duplicate records in queries, I would like ensure that records being inserted at unique.

As far as I know, the only way to do achieve uniqueness is to have a unique S3 key. If I were to opt for this approach, I would end creating couple of million S3 files per day. Each file consists of single json record.

Would creating so many files be an concern when executing Athena queries? 
Any alternatives approaches?

Comment: Each stream record is assigned a sequence number. Could you use this, persisted in a second DynamoDB table, to implement a checkpoint?

Comment: Hmm... I guess in such case I would have to introduce some sort of transactional behavior. e.g. If write to s3 succeeds, then write to the other dynamodb table. If it write to dynamoDb table fails, delete the S3 file? Seems a bit of unnecessary overhead.

Comment: I agree that the idempotent solution is preferable, but I have no data to share on Athena query performance for more smaller files vs. fewer larger files. Certainly it sounds like something that could be tested quite easily.

Comment: Yes it indeed affect the performance of your query.For example if you have a 100 MB file with 1 million records then Athena has to list it,open,read and close it once.Consider a scenario where you have 1 million files each with record then Athena has to list all of them,open,read,close million times which drastically affect the query performance.So ideal file size should be around 128 MB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you would be better off handling the deduplication in Athena itself. For Athena, weeding out a few duplicates will be an easy job. Set up a view that groups by the unique property and uses [`ARBITRARY`](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/0.172/functions/aggregate.html#arbitrary) or [`MAX_BY`](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/0.172/functions/aggregate.html#max_by) (if you have something to order by to pick the latest) for the non-unique properties, and run your queries against this view to not have to worry about deduplication in each individual query.

You could also run a daily or weekly deduplication job using [CTAS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/create-table-as.html), depending on how fresh the data has to be (you can also do complex hybrids with pre-deduplicated historical data union'ed with on-the-fly-deduplicated data).

When running a query Athena lists the objects on S3, and this is not a parallelizable operation (except for partitioned tables where it's parallelizable to the grain of the partitioning), and S3's listings are limited to a page size of 1000. You really don't want to have Athena queries against tables (or partitions) with more than 1000 files.

Comment: if i have a lot of records (in millions), wouldn't using `MAX`  slow down query significantly?

Comment: No, not significantly. It's going to be many orders of magnitude faster than having millions of files. It would of course be quicker to not have to deduplicate at all, but I given that Athena is not exactly low latency to start with I don't think you will notice the difference. If it starts becoming a problem you should run periodic deduplication jobs like in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Write to S3 via a Kinesis Firehose and then query that via Athena. The Firehose will group your records into a relatively small number of files, such that it will then be efficient to query them via Athena. Indeed, it will even organize them into a folder structure that is nicely partitioned by write timestamp.